# chain querysets while preserving chaining order and queryset behaviour

Tags: python, django, django-admin, python-itertools, django-1.5

I am trying to chain querysets while preserving their chaining order.

something like:

```
def queryset(self, request):
    qs = super(EstateAdmin, self).queryset(request).exclude(display_status_id__name='offline')
    new_estates = qs.exclude(Q(purposes__purpose_id=BaseSearchBoxForm.TO_RENT_ID)).filter(Q(
        create_date_time__gte=datetime.datetime.now() - datetime.timedelta(
            days=settings.IS_NEW_ESTATE_DELTA)))

    new_prices = qs.filter(Q(price_change_date_time__gte=datetime.datetime.now() - datetime.timedelta(
        days=settings.IS_NEW_PRICE_DELTA)))
    the_rest = qs
    return new_estates + new_prices + the_rest
```

I tried to use itertools.chain but it does not behave as a queryset.

The purpose of this is to customize an admin change_list queryset to order it in three categories.

Comment: Have you tried doing `order_by('evaluation')` instead? This will give you the order you want, unless your `change_list` view is custom. In latter case try doing it manually.

Comment: True, my example was bad, updated the question

Answer (score -1):

Try [Q objects](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects). Then you can do something like this:

```
from django.db.models import Q

good_products = Q(evaluation__lte=2)
average_products = Q(evaluation__lte=5) & good_products
the_rest = Q(evaluation__gte=5)

queryset = Product.objects.filter(good_products & average_products & the_rest)
```

Comment: I want to keep chining order